# Конфигурация Log4j 2 через JSON

Tags: java, log4j2

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "name": "TestLog",
        "packages": "net.bleser",
        "status": "info",
        "appenders": {
            "Console": {
                "name": "console"
            },
            "File": {
                "name": "File",
                "fileName": "file%d{dd-MM-yyy}.log",
                "immediateFlush": "false"
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "root": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "AppenderRef": {
                    "ref": "console",
                    "level": "INFO"
                }
            },
            "logger": {
                "name": "net.bleser",
                "level": "info",
                "additivity": "false",
                "AppenderRef": {
                    "ref": "File",
                    "level": "INFO"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Хочу настроить лог в консоль и в файл, но если в `logger` прописать путь до пакета с классами `net.bleser` то все логи идет в файл а консоль же ничего не выводится. Если путь до пакета изменить на любой набор символов, то логи начинают идти в консоль. Примеры с англ. Stackoverflow у меня не работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в флажке `"additivity": "false",`
log4j2 использует идею иерархии логеров - логгер использует свои appender-ы и прокидвает сообщения "предкам" логерам, если additivity = true.
(По-умолчанию значение этого флага true.)
По иерархии. Управляется через именование, имя потомка формируется как <имя_предка>.<имя>, т.е. `net.bleser` - потомок `net`
т.е. в вашем конфиге иерархия будет такая
`root->net->net.bleser`

Т.е. чтобы заработал консольный аппендер из рута для `net.blesser` нужно указать, что `net.blesser` прокидывает свои сообщение до `root`, т.е. указать флаг additivity=true

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "name": "TestLog",
        "packages": "net.bleser",
        "status": "info",
        "appenders": {
            "Console": {
                "name": "console"
            },
            "File": {
                "name": "File",
                "fileName": "file%d{dd-MM-yyy}.log",
                "immediateFlush": "false"
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "root": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "AppenderRef": {
                    "ref": "console",
                    "level": "INFO"
                }
            },
            "logger": {
                "name": "net.bleser",
                "level": "info",
                "additivity": "true",
                "AppenderRef": {
                    "ref": "File",
                    "level": "INFO"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Подскажите еще как задать имя файла с датой в имени? пробовал использовать `RollingFileAppender`(http://pastebin.com/2e9ZJpqa), но создается файл с обычным именем.

Comment: filePattern - это формат названия для архивных файлов. Т.е. текущий лог пишется в "fileName", а когда ротация происходит, то создается файл по шаблону из filePattern

Comment: чтобы ротация происходила по дате, нужно добавить еще TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy в массив policies

Comment: есть смысл добавить расширение .zip и указать дополнительную директорию куда архивные логи будут сбрасываться ("filePattern": "logs/file%d{dd-MM-yyy}.log.zip"). По расширению логер поймет, что нужно сжимать в zip архив

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, понял как работает `RollingFileAppender`, он переименовывает старый файл после того как он достигнет нужного размера))

Comment: Все правильно. Вы можете использовать вот эти стратегии (время, размер и т.д.) https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#TriggeringPolicies

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал настроить через XML.
Этот пример выводит лог в консоль и в файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="cons"/>
        <File name="file" fileName="file%d{dd-MM-yyy}.log" immediateFlush="false"/>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="rewrer" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="file"/>
            <appender-ref ref="cons"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="INFO"/>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Если же пример выше переписать на JSON, то срабатывает только первый `AppenderRef`

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "status": "WARN",
    "appenders": {
      "Console":{"name":"cons"},
      "File": {"name": "file","fileName": "file%d{dd-MM-yyy}.log","immediateFlush":"false"}
    },
    "loggers": {
      "logger": {"name": "net.bleser", "level": "INFO","additivity": "false",
        "AppenderRef": {"ref": "cons"},
        "AppenderRef": {"ref": "file"}
      },
      "root":{"level": "INFO"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: тут аппендры должны быть в массиве